# TypeError: missing required positional argument

Tags: flask, web

This is my code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["name"]
        return redirect (url_for("home", usr="user"))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

@app.route(”/home”, methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home(usr):
    #return render_template("home.html")
    return f"<h1>{usr}</h1>"

@app.route(”/report™)
def report():
    return render_template("report.html")

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I received the following error:

```
TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usr'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\py\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(enviorn, start_response)

File "F:\py\lib\site—packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "F:\py\lib\site-packages\flask_app.py’, line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
```

The error says:
TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usr'.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots. include actual text from your file and format appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
def home(usr):
```

you assume this route will be called with a parameter, but you're not specifying where it is coming from. You can either retrieve it from your route, like so:

```
@app.route("/home/<string:usr>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
```

or you need to retrieve it from your request params:

```
from flask import request
usr = request.args.get('usr')
```

or, if it comes from a form (POST):

```
from flask import request
usr = request.form['usr']
```

When retrieving if from the request parameters, you'd need to delete the `usr` parameter from `def home()`

Answer (score 0):

The following may assist when encountering this issue for unknown reasons.

## Short Answer

I received a similar error when I was incorrectly calling a function wrapper on one of my endpoints.

```
# My usage
@oidc.accept_token
# Correct usage
@oidc.accept_token(True)
```

## Full Answer

This was my incorrect code:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@oidc.accept_token
def home():
    ...
```

It produced the following error:

```
File "~\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view_func'
```

Note that the dispatcher has tripped up and thinks a function called `wrapper()` is my view function instead of `home()`.

I fixed by correctly adding a parameter to the `accept_token` decorator:

```
@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@oidc.accept_token(True)
def home():
    ...
```

I am aware this is not relevant to the original question, but it has the same error message and I could not find any other posts for it, so I am including my solution as a suggestion for others who encounter it :)